# Remove whitespace around text in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Is it possible to remove white space at the end of text with CSS (or optionally with JS)? I've tried all kinds of `display` property, but none of them seem to work. I would need to dynamically insert a `blink-div` at the end of multi line sentence. Currently it's is being added outside of `phrase-div` that contains sample text (which, as a div, is rectangular with white space I don't need). HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div id="writr-div">
    <div id="phrase-div"></div>
    <div id="blink-div"></div>
</div>
```

Please check out the both images:

**Original:**

[image]

**Desired effect** (border and background are for preview purpose):

[image]

EDIT:
Okay, I may haven't made myself clear enough. This is what I want (that's not an absolute position, I need it to be at the end of the sentce, no matter how long it is):

[image]

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Add the background-color to a text element instead.

Comment: I dont see any difference between original and desired output except background and border.

Comment: @Asgeirr thank you but that's not what I want, I don't need any background :)

Comment: @void What I mean is that when you inspect an element in browser, you will highlight a div as a rectangle. I need to remove any empty space so I can add another div next to `text` word, as long as it's even possible.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vp9ttbn9/ is this fine ? adding `display:inline` to `phrase-div`

Comment: @LucaThemes this is not how HTML works ... any element is a rectangular element you cannot have shape around element like you want ... this whitespace belong to the div

Comment: Please provide us with the css you have tried. Anyways, `display:inline` Should work: https://jsfiddle.net/77zoefpg/5/

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was afraid of such answer :) Anyway thank you, I'll try to figure something out using JS.

Comment: even with JS you cannot :) it's not a quesion for JS or CSS ... all the element are rectangular, you cannot remove space, you can adjust thing to obtain what you want ... but you cannot remove space like that

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh, okay. There's so much to learn. At least I can count on you guys ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use span:

```css
#writr-div {
  width:140px;
  border:1px solid;
}
#blink-div {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="writr-div">
    <span id="phrase-div">Some text here and there</span>
    <span id="blink-div"> another text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm gonna accept this as a correct answer, thank you so much :)